# How to get redirected url with php

Tags: php, copy, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get copy a website page, but it redirects after enter it on my browser.

For example,

I enter,
http://www.domain.com/cat/121

it redirects,
http://www.domain.com/cat/121/title-of-the-page/

And when I try to php copy function for "www.domain.com/cat/121"
it is not working...

How can I take the redirected new url?

Comment: Please show a sample of your code.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`...

Answer (score 1):

```
     $url='your url';
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow the redirects
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // no needs to pass the headers to the data stream
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // get the resource without a body
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // accept any server certificate
      curl_exec($ch);

      // get the last used URL
      $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

            curl_close($ch);

         echo $lasturl;
```

this will help you to get the redirected url

Answer (score 0):

Use header function for redirecting to specific url.

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/cat/121');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CMS you can use appropriate plugins.

For instance, For Wordpress you could use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/